# how to render header, footer, menu, only once and only for private routes with react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to fulfill thease 2 requisites, but everytime I handle one, I always violate the other.

I have 3 components (header, menu, footer) that needs to be rendered only once and only for the private route components.

They are class components, and their states receives some data retrieved from the localstorage when the user logs in.

If I place them at the app component, around the route component, I fulfill the "render once" requisite, but they are rendered when a non private route is passed to the route component.

If I place them at the route component, around the private routes, I fulfill the latter requisite, but they are re-rendered every time a private route component is rendered.

How can I fulfill both requisites?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render the header, menu, and footer components into routes that match the same paths as your private routes. Be sure to do this *within* the `Router` but *outside* any `Switch` components. The `Router` ***inclusively*** matches and renders routes (i.e. all matches) whereas the `Switch` ***exclusively*** matches and renders routes (i.e. **only** the first match).

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Route
    path={["/private/path/1", "/private/path/2", ....]}
    component={Header}
  />
  <Route
    path={["/private/path/1", "/private/path/2", ....]}
    component={Menu}
  />
  <Switch>
    ... all regular and private routes
  </Switch>
  <Route
    path={["/private/path/1", "/private/path/2", ....]}
    component={Footer}
  />
</Router>
```

You can cut this down/make more DRY by defining your private routes in an array.

```
const privateRoutes = ["/private/path/1", "/private/path/2", ....];

...

<Router>
  <Route
    path={privateRoutes}
    component={Header}
  />
  <Route
    path={privateRoutes}
    component={Menu}
  />
  <Switch>
    ... all regular and private routes
  </Switch>
  <Route
    path={privateRoutes}
    component={Footer}
  />
</Router>
```

### Demo

[image: Edit how-to-render-header-footer-menu-only-once-and-only-for-private-routes-with-r]

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. I have tryied the second option, but it did not solved the problem. It seams that passing the routes with privateRoutes array is not doing nothing.